# Push Notifications mark as read when checked

Tags: android, push-notification, system-tray

I am using GCM Push Notification and if user take a look for notification on system tray and clicked on notification for read, i want this notification mark as read on system tray instead of dismiss this, How can i achieve this? any help will be appreciated. 
Here is my notification code

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher_logo;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        pref = new PrefsHelper(context);

        updateNotification = pref.getNotificationID() + 1;

        pref.setNotificationID(updateNotification);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        int diff = (int)System.currentTimeMillis();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(message);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =  NotificationManagerCompat
            .from(context);



        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification.Builder bilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        bilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_logo);
        bilder.setSubText("");
        bilder.setTicker(message);
        bilder.setContentIntent(intent);

        bilder.setContentTitle(title);
        bilder.setContentText(message);
        /*bilder.setOngoing(true);*/
        bilder.setAutoCancel(false);




        // set intent so it does not start a new activity


        //notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//      notification. (context, title, message, intent);


        // Play default notification sound
        /*notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +
        // context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;*/

        notificationManager.notify(diff, bilder.build());

    }
```

Comment: Can you post what you had try.

Comment: I only tried getting notifications from GCM. is there any need to share ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `notifyID` to [update the current notification](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html) when it is clicked to "update" its content and "mark it as read":

```
((NotificationManager) notificationManager).notify(
    notifyID,
    notifyBuilder.build()
);
```

*This ID is a "unique ID", so when you send multiple notifications with the same ID, each notification will override the previous one.*

Comment: if i setOngoing(true) then user is not able to dismiss the notifications, but my case is different i only want to mark read notification as read and change color of notification or set read flag on system tray.

Comment: So you can forget about the `setOngoing` and use the `notifyID` to update the clicked notification